# rewriting url in asp.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have my url like this-

```
http://localhost:2332/Home/Video?vd_id=525&videoview=63
```

I want it something like this- `Home/Video/525/63` and remove the query portion.

For this I tried resetting this url in `Route.config`-

```
   public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute("newRoute",
                   "Video",
                   new { controller = "Home", action = "Video" },
                   new { action = "Video" }
           );

        }
    }
```

But this url has not any change in it.
How Do I map it's route so it looks for SEO purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two way. Either using the "convention based routing" way or using the new "attribute routing" feature offered by MVC5.

//Process 1: Convention-based Routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default2",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Video", id1 = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

//Process 2: Attribute Routing:
You can achieve this very easily using attribute routing. To enable Attribute Routing, we need to call the MapMvcAttributeRoutes method of the route collection class during configuration.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
     {
         routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

         //Add the following line of code
         routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //[Code Excerpt]
     }
}
```

A route attribute has to be defined on top of an action method or on the top of a controller.

```
  [RoutePrefix("Home")]
  [Route("{action=index}")]
  public class HomeController:Controller
  {
       [Route("Video/{id?}/{id2?}")]
       public ActionResult Video()
       {
            //your code goes here
            return View();
       }
```

For details check: http://learnwithshahriar.wordpress.com/2014/05/08/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc5/

Answer (score 0):

Add this above the others. You don't really need that last one as it will be automatically mapped onto the default/default2 routes. The defaults parameter is only applied when there are no parameters at all.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And then when you generate the URL

Html.ActionLink("Your link text", "action", new { id="XXX", id2="YYY")")

Comment: I still see url with parameters like this- `http://localhost:2332/Home/Video?vd_id=525&videoview=63`

Answer (score -3):

Specify url as below

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Home","Video")/10/20">Video</a>
```